# How to refresh jquery ui slider with pips

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to implement this jquery-ui-slider-pips plugin: http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/

**What I'm trying to achieve:** Have the second slider update when the first one changes.

**What's actually happening:** In the sliderChange function, if I remove the last line (commented out in code below), the second slider doesn't fully update, when it's there it updates correctly but I get an error from the plugin "originalMousedown is not a function".

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with my code?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Forever_Nomad/8udy118k/

**Code:**

```
var start1 = 100;
var start2 = 50;
var max1 = 1000;
var max2 = start1;
var percent = 50;

var slider1 = $("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: max1,
    value: start1,
    range: "min",
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value < start1) { 
            $(this).slider('value',start1);
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-tip').text(parseInt(start1));
            return false;
        }
    },
    change: function(event,ui){
        sliderChange(ui);
    }
}).slider('pips').slider('float');

var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: max2,
    value: start2,
    range: "min",
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.value < start2) { 
            $(this).slider('value',start2);
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-tip').text(parseInt(start2));
            return false;
        }
    }
}).slider('pips').slider('float');

function sliderChange(data){
    var val = data.value * (percent / 100);
    start2 = val;
    slider2.slider('option', 'min', 0);
    slider2.slider('option', 'max', parseInt(data.value));
    slider2.slider('option', 'value', start2);
    //slider2.slider('pips').slider('float');
}
```

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to the latest version: https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/tree/master/dist ... the latest version unbinds the `mousedown` event properly, which should fix your js error.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Hadn't realised it had been updated, I only grabbed the files on the 10th Sep and got v1.10.5. Now, how do I give you the rep for finding a solution?